# It is a flow chart asking to create a program to troubleshoot wifi

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWdXg.jpg)

Hi I need to know why my python code keeps doing infinite loop when i execute it. where on my code can I have errors? It is a flow chart asking to create a program to troubleshoot wifi. if the solution presented to user does not work, it will ask the user if it fixed his/her problem. If the user input 'n', it will provide another solution. it will goes for 3,4 solutions until it says you need to replace the router, but when it hits the replacing the router, on execution, the replace router massage goes on and program never stops.

```
error_fixed = 'n'


while error_fixed == 'n':
    print ('reboot computer')
    error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
    while error_fixed == 'n':
        print ('reboot router')
        error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
        while error_fixed == 'n':
            print('check cable connections')
            error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
            while error_fixed == 'n':
                print('move router to new location')
                error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
                while error_fixed == 'n':
                    print('replace the router')
```

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

When you get here:

```
 while error_fixed == 'n':
    print('replace the router')
```

`error_fixed` is `'n'`; that's how you got to `print('replace the router')`.

But then you do not update `error_fixed`, so it stays `'n'`

Do you mean to ask the user again after 'replace the router', or do you just want to exit the loop after printing 'replace the router'?

If the latter, you could change that part to:

```
while error_fixed == 'n':
    print('replace the router')
    break
```

But that will only break out of the inner while.

You could change it to:

```
 while error_fixed == 'n':
    print('replace the router')
    error_fixed == 'y'
```

That would end all the loops but might be a bit of a lie :-)

The best solution would probably be one while loop, with a list of error messages, and as long as the error is not fixed you increment the message index and print the next message.  Then `break` would work.  Iterating over the list and using `break` to exit if the problem is fixed makes nicer python code.  Something like this:

```
suggestions = ['reboot computer', 'reboot router', 'check cable connections','move router to new location','replace the router']

for suggestion in suggestions:
    print suggestion
    error_fixed = raw_input('Did that fix your problem? ')
    if (error_fixed == 'y'):
        break
```

Note that I changed `input` to `raw_input`.  You don't have to use this suggestion.  I did it because when you use input the user has to enter his `y` or `n` answer in quotation marks, like this `"n"`.  I found it more convenient when testing to enter just `n` or `y`, without the quotes.

If you want it to look more like your original code, You could also do it similar to what you wrote, changing the "while"s to "if"s so they won't repeat:

```
print ('reboot computer')
error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
if error_fixed == 'n':
    print ('reboot router')
    error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
    if error_fixed == 'n':
        print('check cable connections')
        error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
        if error_fixed == 'n':
            print('move router to new location')
            error_fixed = input('Did problem fixed? ')
            if error_fixed == 'n':
                print('replace the router')
```